# How to implement google play leader board in andengine?

Tags: andengine, leaderboard

Please tell me how to implement google play service leader board in andengine ?

Is there any tutorial ?

I searches all the questions on google regarding my question but did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a few things you need to do here.

1) Import BaseGameUtils into your project. You can download it from [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils)

2) Update your build.gradle file dependencies to include it

`dependencies {
....
     compile project(':BaseGameUtils’)
....`

3) Make sure you’ve updated your manifest correctly

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
………

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application …….
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
……
```

4) Modify the name of BaseGameActivity in BaseGameUtils to e.g. GMSBaseGameActivity and make it extend SimpleBaseGameActivity or BaseGameActivity (whichever you’re using). Then update **your** main activity to extend GMSBaseGameActivity (overriding onSignInFailed and onSignInSucceeded).

Now you’re app should automatically connect when it starts.

Use `getGameHelper().isSignedIn()` to query if the user is signed in.

Use `startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getGameHelper().getApiClient(), getResources().getString(R.string.your_leaderboard_id)), 0);` to display the leaderboard

Use `Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getGameHelper().getApiClient(), getResources().getString(R.string.your_leaderboard_id), this_is_the_score_submitted);` to submit a score.